# Laravel filter array based on element value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following array that I need to filter it and get just the elements which have `type = 1`

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Agua Corriente"
    "type" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Cloaca"
    "type" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Gas Natural"
    "type" => 2
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "Internet"
    "type" => 3
  ]
  4 => array:3 [
    "id" => 5
    "name" => "Electricidad"
    "type" => 3
  ]
]
```

This is the expected result:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Agua Corriente"
    "type" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Cloaca"
    "type" => 1
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to solve it with `Arr::where` helper but I'm not getting the expected result.
Does anyone can help me?

Regards

Comment: *I'm trying to solve it with Arr::where helper*, can you show what you have tried and perhaps we can help with what isn't working.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php is your friend

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$filteredArray = Arr::where($myArray, function ($value, $key) {
    return $value['type'] == 1;
});
```

This is how you can use `Arr::where` in your array, and should work fine.

Also for things like this ***laravel collections*** have really handy tools, you should have a look at it as well.

If you want to filter based on a dynamically assigned variable, which most of the times is the case you can simply inject it in your nested function like:

```
    $type = 1;
    $filteredArray = Arr::where($myArray, function ($value, $key) use($type) {
        return $value['type'] == $type;
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `array_filter` and inside give the condition you need.

```
$data = array_filter($array, function ($item) {
    return $item["type"] === 1;
});

print_r($data);
```

Comment: This non-laravel (general PHP) advice has been given on Stack Overflow many times prior to 2020.

Answer (score 5):

You can use collection `where`:

```php
collect($array)->where('type', 1)->all();
```